Given a rust `Vec` on a type defined using the newtype idiom, Is there a way to have a slice of the underlying original type?
In other words, if I have defined a type like e.g.
pub struct MyFloat(f64);

is it possible to have something like this?
let v = vec![MyFloat(0.),MyFloat(1.)];
let v_slice_f64 : &[f64] = v.slice_underlying_type();
assert_eq!(v_slice_f64, &[0.,1.]);

This is because I would like to wrap the native f64 with the newtype idiom, but some libraries I use require &[f64] as input argument in their methods.

dupes: How do I convert a Vec to a Vec without copying the vector?, How to fix runtime overhead caused by newtype in array just s/(vec|array)/slice/

What you're attempting is not safe because struct MyFloat(T) is not technically guaranteed to have the same representation as T for arbitrary T - even it most likely will in the case of f64. If you control MyFloat, you can add #[repr(transparent)] to provide that guarantee.
You can make use of the excellent bytemuck crate, which provides its own traits and functions for safe casting:
use bytemuck::{Pod, Zeroable};

#[derive(Pod, Zeroable, Copy, Clone)]
#[repr(transparent)]
struct MyFloat(f64);

fn main() {
    let v = vec![MyFloat(0.), MyFloat(1.)];
    let v_slice_f64: &[f64] = bytemuck::cast_slice(&v);
    assert_eq!(v_slice_f64, &[0., 1.]);
}

Playground
bytemuck's derive macros will ensure that you use #[repr(transparent)] or equivalent to make the slicing operation actually sound.
If you want to do it using only stdlib, you'll have to use unsafe. I wouldn't recommend it, but it would look like this:
#[repr(transparent)]
struct MyFloat(f64);

// Transmute slice of T to slice of U, while keeping the lifetime.
// SAFETY: `T` and `U` must have compatible layout, and every `T`
// value must be represented in memory as a valid `U` value.
unsafe fn transmute_slice<'a, T, U>(s: &'a [T]) -> &'a [U] {
    std::slice::from_raw_parts(s.as_ptr() as *const U, s.len())
}

fn main() {
    let v = vec![MyFloat(0.), MyFloat(1.)];
    // SAFETY: MyFloat is transparent, so they have identical layouts,
    // and every `MyFloat` is a valid `f64` in memory.
    let v_slice_f64: &[f64] = unsafe { transmute_slice(&v) };
    assert_eq!(v_slice_f64, &[0., 1.]);
}

Playground
